# How to convert object data into json string in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am getting result in object and want to convert into json and I am not understand how to do this so I need help.

My `object` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 85
            [username] => Chang Sindelar
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 84
            [username] => Ezekiel Watterson
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 83
            [username] => Sylvester Hillebrand
        )
)
```

And I want to convert into `json` string. I need result somthing like this:

```
{"85":"Chang Sindelar","84":"Ezekiel Watterson","83":"Sylvester Hillebrand"}
```

Any Idea.

Thanks.

Comment: How you are getting this object data?

Comment: @Gautam3164 I am getting this data in PDO query.

Comment: As long as you don't want to change the json back to an object, you can use the PHP JsonSerializable interface: http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not with the JSON encoding, but the mapping of your objects' properties to an associative array.

Mapping your objects into one associative array can be done using `array_reduce`:

```
$array = [
    (object) ['user_id' => 85, 'username' => 'Chang Sindelar'],
    (object) ['user_id' => 84, 'username' => 'Ezekiel Watterson'],
    (object) ['user_id' => 83, 'username' => 'Sylvester Hillebrand']
];

$assoc = array_reduce($array, function($result, $item) {
    $result[$item->user_id] = $item->username;
    return $result;
}, []);
```

The `$assoc` variable will now hold an associative array like this:

```
array(3) {
  [85]=>
  string(14) "Chang Sindelar"
  [84]=>
  string(17) "Ezekiel Watterson"
  [83]=>
  string(20) "Sylvester Hillebrand"
}
```

To get your JSON, simply run `$assoc` through `json_encode`:

```
$json = json_encode($assoc);
// {"85":"Chang Sindelar","84":"Ezekiel Watterson","83":"Sylvester Hillebrand"}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `type casting` you can change them into array like

```
$array = (array) $my_object;
```

Or even you can use `get_object_vars` like

```
$array = get_object_vars($my_object);
```

Or from your PDO query result them as `array`

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop and create an new vector (array), after use json_encode, example:

```
$vector = array();
$size = count($obj); //$obj contain your "array"
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
   $vector[((string) $obj[$i]->user_id)] = $obj[$i]->username;
}

echo json_encode($vector);
```

Comment: Getting error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$username_id in /var/www/xxxx/application/controller/board.php on line 320
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$username_id in /var/www/xxxx/application/controller/board.php on line 320
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$username_id in /var/www/xxxx/application/controller/board.php on line 320`

Answer (score 0):

using this function will return your object into an array of properties of that object.

```
array get_object_vars ( object $object )
return get_object_vars($your_object_variable_here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach($arr as $v) {
 $newarr[$v->user_id] = $v->username;
}
echo json_encode($newarr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Objects dont JSON encode very well, but you can convert it first to an associative array, and then convert to JSON: e.g.

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
$jsonstring = json_encode ($array)
```

Comment: "Objects don't JSON encode very well" is an imprecise and unclear statement. I'm not sure what you mean, so I can't say you're wrong. But you're wrong.